# Is there any difference between INSTR() and CHARINDEX()?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I was wondering if there was a difference (other than the engine compatibility and the optional occurence) between

```
CHARINDEX (expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [, start_location])
```

and

```
INSTR (string , substring [, position [, occurrence]])
```

Thank you.

Comment: tag the dbms you are using

Comment: Between INSTR (Oracle) and CHARINDEX (SQL Server) you mean? If so, http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/instr

Comment: This question was meant between Oracle and SQL S. Thank you @Max !

Comment: http://sqlbank.blogspot.com/2010/01/sql-server-charindex-oracle-instr.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Usage: `INSTR( string1, string2 [, start_position [, nth_appearance ] ] )`
>   Usage: `CHARINDEX ( expression1 , expression2 [ , start_location ] )`
>
> - [Source](http://sqlbank.blogspot.be/2010/01/sql-server-charindex-oracle-instr.html)

Except the difference of [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) it runs on, `CHARINDEX` is the same as `INSTR` except for `nth_appearance` that can't be set using `CHARINDEX`.